# I'm trying to insert a <br/> in the text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to move the button under the `textarea` from js-code. But I can't make it happen!

```
var mybr = document.createElement('br');
var targetInnerHtml = obj.innerHTML;
var textArea= document.createElement('textarea');
var parentnode = obj.parentNode;
parentnode.insertBefore(textArea, obj);
parentnode.insertBefore(textArea, obj);
parentnode.insertBefore(mybr,obj.nextSibling); //this is not working either...
// document.write('<br />'); //tried this but nothing
//parentnode.appendChild(mybr); //this either
parentnode.insertBefore(butt, obj);
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Could you post a live [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show what you're working with?

Comment: @Dadid Ive updated it. pls have a look at the link!

Comment: that's a picture; it doesn't much help us to see the code that's active on yout page... ;)

Comment: @David Thomas nice! I'll do that...dont know I've the time now. tonight for sure!! thanks!

Comment: @David Thomas here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/yoniGeek/AHwBb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't got time to test, right now, but can you not simply set the `display` of the `textarea` to `block`:

```
textarea.style.disply = 'block';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4eCcC/).

Comment: Thomas And what about the other suggestions that I have? shall I delete them? thanks

Comment: @YoniGeek, no; don't delete them. They would work (one of them's pretty much the same suggestion as my own), find the one that works best for your use-case and accept that as the answer. Either vote the other answers up if they were helpful, or leave them be. Only delete/vote-down if the answers were actively harmful or very, very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

just put your textarea inside a div so it will occupy the whole line

Comment: hi! umean createElement ("div"). Add the textArea inside and then append it before obj like Im doing?